# Magento 2.1 UI component form addFieldToFilter() on null

Tags: magento-2.1, module, collection, uicomponent, data-provider

I am trying to make a **UI component** form for **creating products** in Magento 2.1 module. However, I stuck with the problem that it throws this error:

> Fatal error: Method
>   Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
>   exception, caught Error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter()
>   on null in
>   /home/nikolay/Projects/project_name/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php
>   on line 0

I think that it's causing an error because I don't have any collection to pass for DataProvider. But the thing is that I don't need one. So I am trying to figure out how to avoid this error without having any collection to pass.

**/Model/DataProvider.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company_Name\ProductParser\Model;

use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $data);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }

}
```

**view/adminhtml/layout/productparser_parseproduct_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Parse
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="parse_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**view/adminhtml/ui_component/parse_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">parse_form.parse_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">parse_form.parse_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">parse_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Information</item>
        <!--<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\DeleteButton</item>
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Edit\SaveButton</item>
        </item>-->
        <!--<item name="reverseMetadataMerge" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>-->
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">parse_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="parse_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Company_Name\ProductParser\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">parse_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <!--<item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">field</item>
                </item>-->
                <!--<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="string">admin/productparser/create</item>
                    &lt;!&ndash;<item name="validate_url" xsi:type="string">admin/productparser/validate</item>&ndash;&gt;
                </item>-->
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <!--<item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>-->
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="data">
        <!-- This field represents form id and is hidden -->
        <field name="entity_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">parse_form</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>

        <!-- This field has data type 'text' and standard 'input' form element and looks like input -->
        <field name="title">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Some text</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">parse_form</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 16):

Not sure if this will completely solve your problem, but it should take you a step further.
Add this method in your data provider

```
public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
{
    return null;
}
```

Since you are extending `AbstractDataProvider` you need to override the method.
If something else crashes, you might need to do the same thing for other methods involving `$this->getCollection()`.
I'm thinking one of these methods `addField`, `addOrder`, `setLimit`, `removeField`, `removeAllFields`, `count`

Comment: I'm afraid that causes page bootloop.

Comment: It went to the page bootloop ,So is there any other solution to mitigate this , because I also need similar functionality only form without collection . @Marius

Comment: @ShashankGupta Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: This solution worked for me

Answer (score 8):

Change
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider

To
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider

Comment: It also worked for me, what is the logic behind this, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @AbdulBasit It worked for me, too. Can you please explain what was the reason why \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider was not working?

Comment: I confirm that this worked for me on Magento v2.4.3

Answer (score 3):

The Abstract Data Provider that you are extending has collection field.
You must initialize this field with a valid collection (the collection associated with your entity).

Steps to solve the problem.

1. Inject collectionFactory in the class that extends AbstractDataProvider.
2. Initialize $collection field.

The error message is pretty intuitive too. (By Magento standards).
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just inject your collection factory class in the constructor of your dataprovider and assign the collection member variable with your collection.
It should resolve the issue. Best

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Company_Name\ProductParser\Model;

use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \[mynamespace]\[mymodule]\model\ResourceModel\[myclass]\CollectionFactory $mycollectionFactory,
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $data);
        $this->collection = $mycollectionFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is that Magento is trying to filter the collection based on the id provided in the url, since you added this line in the uiComponent

```
<argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
```

So to filter the collection based on this id, Magento calls the addFilter function in the AbstractDataProvider

```
public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
{
    $this->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter(
        $filter->getField(),
        [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]
    );
}
```

However, because getCollection() return null, as it's relying on the collection variable in the AbstractDateProvider, as you didnt override it in your extended class, you're getting the addFilter on null error.

I would suggested trying to remove the requestFieldName field from the xml, and if that didn't work, override the $collection variable in your extended class with an empty and generic collection in the constructor.