# getCollection return null on custom model collection Magento 2.3.4

Tags: magento2.3, collection, model, resource-model

I'm creating a custom module to make a model by using [mage2gen](https://mage2gen.com), I named this model `critic`:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/Critic.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model;

use Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CriticInterface;
use Vendor\Module\Api\Data\CriticInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper;

/**
 * Class Critic
 *
 * @package Vendor\Module\Model
 */
class Critic extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{

    protected $dataObjectHelper;

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'vendor_module_critic';
    protected $criticDataFactory;


    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param CriticInterfaceFactory $criticDataFactory
     * @param DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Critic $resource
     * @param \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Critic\Collection $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CriticInterfaceFactory $criticDataFactory,
        DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Critic $resource,
        \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Critic\Collection $resourceCollection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->criticDataFactory = $criticDataFactory;
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve critic model with critic data
     * @return CriticInterface
     */
    public function getDataModel()
    {
        $criticData = $this->getData();

        $criticDataObject = $this->criticDataFactory->create();
        $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
            $criticDataObject,
            $criticData,
            CriticInterface::class
        );

        return $criticDataObject;
    }
}
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Critic.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel;

    /**
     * Class Critic
     *
     * @package Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel
     */
    class Critic extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
    {

        /**
         * Define resource model
         *
         * @return void
         */
        protected function _construct()
        {
            $this->_init('vendor_module_critic', 'critic_id');
        }
    }
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Model/ResourceModel/Critic/Collection.php**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Critic;

 /**
 * Class Collection
 *
 * @package Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Critic
 */
 class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
 {

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_idFieldName = 'critic_id';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            \Vendor\Module\Model\Critic::class,
            \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Critic::class
        );
    }
}
```

when i tried to get the data collection like this:

```
public function __construct(
 \Vendor\Module\Model\CriticFactory $criticFactory
){
  $this->criticFactory = $criticFactory;
}

public function execute(){
   $this->criticFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('critic_id','1');
}
```

I always got an error

```
Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on null
```

then I tried to print the `getCollection`, but it returns empty

```
print_r($this->criticFactory->create()->getCollection());
```

then I tried to get the type, then it returns `null`

```
print_r(gettype($this->criticFactory->create()->getCollection()));
```

Comment: Please refer to this answer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176646/magento-2-1-ui-component-form-addfieldtofilter-on-null

Comment: Your code seems all correct. It may be related to file permission issue. Mage2Gen has some issues with file permission when you extract the zip. Please check and correct your file ownership and permissions. Run compilation and check.

Comment: @JaiminSutariya just checked my ownership and permission , run compilation etc still same error

Answer (score 0):

please try to load the collection by **ResourceModel** like instead of this

```
\Vendor\Module\Model\CriticFactory $criticFactory
```

Use this

```
\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Critic\CollectionFactory $criticFactory
```

then run the `setup:di:compile` and check.

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Could you please try to load the collection by ResourceModel like
instead of this
\Vendor\Module\Model\CriticFactory $criticFactory
Use this
\Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Critic\CollectionFactory $criticFactory

Comment: it works, but how cant i use the factory like in Magento 2 previous version ? how can i add new data using this factory?

Comment: @jojo, I have updated my answer using my above comment. also, please accept the answer and upvote, So it will help others.